# How to use JavaScript onclick event handler -WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions in Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, asp.net, xcode, dom-events

I am writing iOS application to access data on website. It has username and password. So far I am unable to log into website programmatically. Below is aspx code for Login button

```
<div class="formRow formRowFull">
                    <label class="formLabel span4">
                        &nbsp;
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Log in" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;required&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" class="mrg14 inputButton" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; <a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="noteupload1" target="_parent" href="Forgot-Password.aspx" title="Forgot Password">
                        Forgot Password ?</a>
                </div>
```

I tried below code

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit').submit();"];
```

And

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;required&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"];
```

Above code used to work with html. I guess WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is .NET framework method. I found below links related to this
http://www.carlosag.net/articles/webparts/whidbey-faq
and
http://plainoldstan.blogspot.in/2007/06/story-of-client-side-validation-in.html
But I didn't understand much.

How can I programmatically click this button?